# Installing MySQLi to MAMP

Tags: php, mysqli, mamp

I use MAMP for local development on mac.
I could not get data from MySQL table, and I was recommended to install MySQLi. How to install MySQLi to MAMP?

Comment: Does the mysqli extension not come bundled?  Check the output from `phpinfo()` and look for the mysqli extension.

Answer (score 2):

MAMP comes with MySQLi.

From the MAMP homepage http://localhost:8888/MAMP/ click on the php_info link and then search for MySQLi.  You will find all the details there.

If it doesn't have MySQLi you may have a very old version.  If so upgrade to the latest.